# Idiomatic way to unwrap an integer string input

Tags: swift

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I am learning Swift and I don’t understand how to unwrap inputs from `readLine()`.

For example, I would expect this

```
let n: Int = Int(readLine(strippingNewline: true) ?? -1)
```

to work, but it doesn’t. Nor does replacing the `-1` with a `"-1"` to match types.

```
let n: Int = Int(readLine(strippingNewline: true) ?? "-1")
```

What is the “right” way to do this then? Can someone explain exactly what Swift is doing when it unwraps optionals and uses them as arguments for a constructor like `Int`?

The whole concept of optionals is a bit foreign to me (a Python programmer); in Python you handle invalid input the “ghetto way”, putting out fires only after they happen:

```
try:
    n = int(input())
except ValueError:
    n = None
```

but I assume the paradigm in Swift is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two optionals at play here.

First, `readLine(strippingNewline: true)` is optional. It can return `nil` if there's no input recieved prior to the `End of File` (`EOF`) character being received. It must be unwrapped before being passed into `Int()`

Secondly, `Int()` is optional, because the `String` it was given may not be a valid string representation of a number.

Do not use `-1` in Swift to represent "no value". This is called a sentinel value, and it's exactly what optionals are invented to **prevent.** How do you distinguish between a `-1` meaning "no/invalid input", and a `-1` meaning "the user's input was `-1`?

Here is how I would write this code:

```
guard let userInput = readLine(strippingNewline: true) else {
    // If we got to here, readLine(strippingNewLine:) returned nil
    fatalError("Received EOF before any input was given")
}

// If we got to here, then userInput is not nil

if let n = Int(userInput) {
    // If we got to here, then userInput contained a valid
    // String representation of an Int
    print("The user entered the Int \(n)")
}
else {
    // If we got to here, then userInput did not contain a
    // valid String representation of an Int.
    print("That is not a valid Int.")
}
```

Comment: Why does Int() require an unwrapped value itself then, if it is already capable of returning a `nil`?

Comment: Because propagating the error forward like that makes it hard to find out exactly which stage the `nil` came from. Furthermore, if `Int()` accepted a `String?` rather than `String`, then every-time it was called with a `String`, that `String` would need to be wrapped to make it a `String?`

Comment: Also, slightly unrelated to the original question, but what does `guard` do here? Why isn’t it being used on the second check?

Comment: `guard` is like an assertion. It says `"I assert that userInput = readLine(strippingNewline: true), and it's not nil, otherwise, do this: (fatalError, or whatever)."`

Comment: `guard` forces you to exis the scope by using `break`, `return`, `continue`, `throw` or calling a function that returns `Never`, such as `fatalError`. This way, there's no way the program can resume past the `guard` if `userInput` is `nil`

Comment: Guard is discussed near the bottom of this page of the Swift language guide, under the heading "Early Exit" https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Okay, so if I want to take a user value if provided, and set the variable to 0 else, is this the correct way to do it? `let n: Int = Int(readLine(strippingNewline: true) ?? "") ?? 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128318/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-taylor-swift).